# Page contents floats left and center align when page scrolling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The page contents floats left initially and when scrolled down it displays in the center of the page.

Please see https://buckbaaz.com/category/photography/

I could not find out the CSS issue

Any help?

Code

```
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center pad20">
             <h1>Category : <?php the_category(', '); ?></h1>
        </div>
    <?php    
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>  


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
             <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>
             <?php
                if (is_category( $category = 'Photography' ) ) {
                    if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                echo '<div class="postthumb">';
                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                echo '</div>';

                  }
                }
             ?>
        </div>
    <?php   
    endwhile;

    // Archive doesn't exist:
    else :

        esc_html__( 'Nothing found, sorry.','north' );

    endif;    

    vntd_pagination();       



    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: What you're providing is still not enough, please provide the css, and since php isn't meaningfull here I'd also advise to replace it with the compiled html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your page-content DIV full width:

```
#page-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Ther's still a weird "stutter" when you scroll back to top though